# How to call a function within html doc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a named function that gets 2 params. First param is an image filename (str) without his expression. Second param is image height (num) in pixels.
I want to display image with given height within html document.

eg:

```
<div><script>showImage('test', 100);</script></div>
```

I believe that function is not called the right way.. How to correctly call the function to display images inside any div.

```js
function showImage (imgfilename, imgheight) {
 var img = '';
 imgheight = typeof(imgheight) !== "undefined" ? imgheight : "64";
 imgheight = 64 + (imgheight - 64);
 img += '<img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/'+imgfilename+'.png" width="64px" height="'+imgheight+'px">';
 //console.log (img);
 return img;
}
```

```css
body {background-color: #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="img1"><script>showImage('7a622f4233', 68);</script></div>

<div id="img2"><script>showImage('7a622f4233', 80);</script></div>

<div id="img3"><script>showImage('7a5fa34d31', 60);</script></div>
```

Comment: damn! you see something new every day

Comment: Why are you trying to do it like this? Why don't you just add the image's src attribute normally?

Comment: You are mixing concepts and howewer why you require to call script at that position.

Comment: what role does `imgheight = 64 + (imgheight - 64);` have ??

Comment: height pass as number eg 100, 110 and soo on..
if height is 100 then image height is 64px  if height is 110 then image hight is 74px.. 
The problem anyway is not the hight but how to call corectly this function inside html

Comment: But...`64 + (110 - 64)` gives a result of `110`. The two `64`s cancel each other out.

Comment: nnnnnnn my original image is 420px and represents an object 1m. When i want to display an object 1.10m passing 110 ...
Soo i made this to display correct the hights


imgheight = typeof(pH) !== "undefined" ? imgheight : "100";

imgheight = 420 + (imgheight - 100);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

Use data attributes to store your info

```
<div class="img" data-id="7a622f4233" data-height="68"></div>

<div class="img" data-id="7a622f4233" data-height="80"></div>

<div class="img" data-id="7a5fa34d31" data-height="60"></div>
```

js:

```
$('.img').each(function(){
    var imgheight =$(this).attr('data-height');
    var imgfilename = $(this).attr('data-id');
    imgheight = imgheight != "" ? imgheight : "64";
    var img = '<img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/'+imgfilename+'.png" width="64px" height="'+imgheight+'px">';
 $(this).html(img);
})
```

Comment: Where do `imgheight` and `imgfilename` come from? (The code shown never gets the values from the `data-` attributes...)

Comment: @nnnnnn sory my bad:)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a string, but you should add the img to the DOM, as

```
function showImage (imgfilename, imgheight, elementId) {
    var img = '';
    imgheight = typeof(imgheight) !== "undefined" ? imgheight : "64";
    imgheight = 64 + (imgheight - 64);
    img += '<img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/'+imgfilename+'.png" width="64px" height="'+imgheight+'px">';
    //console.log (img);
    $("#" + elementId).append(img);
}
```

And calling the method with:

```
<div id="img1"><script>showImage('7a622f4233', 68, 'img1');</script></div>
```

Edit: the solution of madalin ivascu is also a very good one, however it is a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a lot of reading. That's no way to call a function and to return an html element within a script tag?

First off, correct your function to append the generated html into another element:

```
function showImage (imgfilename, imgheight, imgId) {
    var img = '';
    imgheight = typeof(imgheight) !== "undefined" ? imgheight : "64";
    imgheight = 64 + (imgheight - 64);
    img += '<img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/'+imgfilename+'.png" width="64px" height="'+imgheight+'px">';
    //console.log (img);

document.getElementById(imgId).innerHTML = img;
}
```

Then call it like this:

`showImage('name', height, 'imgId');`

And please remove the script tags from the divs:

`<div id="img1"></div>`

Comment: Not all of them are correct actually, but madalin's is the most elegant, since you are already using jQuery.

Comment: `.innerHTML()` isn't a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="img1"><script>document.write(showImage('7a622f4233', 68));</script></div>
```

You need to write your returned `img` tag out.

Comment: What will happen ? What you mean ? Can not use `script` here ?@Ted

Comment: @Ted - What do you think should happen to the script tags? The user can't see them...

Comment: @nnnnnn  yes , this is doable .

Comment: The script tags will remain as they are and you will end up with an img element within script tags. That's simply wrong and illogical. Script tags should contain scripts, not html elements

Comment: @Ted `script` is not visiable and `dojo` use the way a lot , this is not a perfect way , but can not say this is a wrong way .

Comment: @passion - couldn't care less what dojo does, it's still wrong and not W3C comlpiant. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp